# swift heightForRowAt indexPath not update

Tags: swift, height, cell, heightforrowatindexpath, indexpath

With this code I set automatic dimension of a cell based on the number of items in array.
It works, but when I add some new item with another viewController and then return to this the height does'n update even if the number of array get increased.

I get the array in viewDidAppear

can someone help me?

```js
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        
      print("called")        
        
           let misure = self.array.count
 
            let cellHeight = CGFloat(50.0 * Float(misure))
            
            print(cellHeight)
            print(misure, " misure")

            let section = indexPath.section
            let row = indexPath.row
            if section == 3 && row == 0{
                return 100.0
            }else if section == 4 && row == 0{
                return cellHeight + 60.0
            }
            return 44.0
        
        
    }
```

in viewDidLoad I have set

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
```

Comment: Are you updating array when the data is added in the ViewController?

Comment: yes, the array return the correct number of items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow I found a solution!

Thanks to this answer: [Swift: How to reload row height in UITableViewCell without reloading data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406632/swift-how-to-reload-row-height-in-uitableviewcell-without-reloading-data)

Just used

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

in viewDidAppear

I hope that it will help someone else!

Answer (score 1):

I think if you call `tableView.layoutIfNeeded()` should be better. This will update any layout updates that are in a pending state. Didn't try to modify the height with this, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

call tableView.reloadData() after getting the array update