# Table view cell dynamic height expands but showing empty view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

Here table view cell height was expanded but the `label` content view was not properly displayed but `button action` triggered in the bottom position of the `view` can anyone help me to sort out this?

[image: This was the design of the image]

[image: dynamic label constraints which I had given]

**The code used is**

```
self.cancelOrderTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
self.cancelOrderTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return 300
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

Comment: do other labels in cell have fixed height?

Comment: yes all have heights for labels except the coloured label @KeshuRai

Comment: make sure numberOfLines = 0 for label and Submit button is constrained to the bottom of the cell. Also, remove the height constraint on UILabel.

Comment: yes had done but still it shows empty space and when i click on the button position in view it works and not showing in view @KeshuRai

Comment: it's visible now @Fogmeister

Comment: check this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/37406758/8374890

Comment: tried but didn't works @KeshuRai

Comment: Did you set attribute properly? did you check the data properly passing or not else please elaborate details.