# Constraint is deactivated by the system

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have a constraint in my view controller that gets deactivated by the system for some reason when the app goes into the background and then coming back to foreground. I haven't been able to pinpoint who's deactivating the constraint. I subclassed `NSLayoutConstraint` to catch when it's deactivated but the precondition is never triggered. So I'm out of ideas why this is happening and how to prevent it.

```
@IBOutlet private(set) var testConstraint: TestConstraint!


class TestConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint {
    override var isActive: Bool {
        didSet {
            precondition(isActive, "isActive should not be set to false")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a general rule, constraints to not get *"deactivated by the system for some reason "* ... try putting together a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the constraint **is not** installed (deactivated) in interface builder for some reason it will be deactivated by the system.

I haven't found any documentation for this but I found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58633374/294661) which led me to test to activate the constraint in interface builder and sure enough it stays active when coming from the background.